# How to remove all the special characters like "RS" (record separator)

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I want to ask what is the best way to use php to remove unwanted special characters like RS?
because if I contain such characters in my xml document, it makes the client program parsing failed.

(the data source contains both english and chinese characters)

thx!!

Comment: If the data source contains chinese characters, it must be Unicode.  How do you expect PHP to handle a unicode file reliably/easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) for all [special characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) codes (is very fast):

```
$output = strtr($input, "\x1E\x06", "  "); // Remove RS and ACK
```

(there is 2 chars inside the first and 2 spaces inside the second string)

or a range with [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$output = preg_replace("/[\x1C-\x1F]/", "", $input); // Remove FS GS RS US
```

Answer (score 1):

If your document is fairly small, just use str_replace in php. It's good enough.
But for longer/bigger document, I'd like to suggest to use 'streamable' way - like tr.

example : `$ tr -d 'RS' < original.xml > output.xml`

or it's better to make your own in php.

Comment: if i use str_replace, what should i put in the $search? 

str_replace ( $search , $replace , $subject [, int &$count ] )

Comment: like this : $result = str_replace( 'RS', '', $original );